# Elisp how to tell if my cursor is inside an org-table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have some code that activates hydras based on modes.

I can do the following for `org-mode`:

```
(when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
  (hydra-org-nav/body))
```

I would like to see if I'm in an `org-table` and call my `org-table` hydra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-table-p` is the function you want, although it does not appear to have a docstring.

I figured this out by using `apropos`, coupled with common elisp naming conventions:

- prefix functions with the package name (here, `org-table...`)
- end predicate functions (that return `t` or `nil`) with `-p`

So: `M-x apropos org-table -p`, and browse the options.

Comment: Interesting, `org-table-p` just calls `org-at-table-p`. That could be why there is not doc on it.

Comment: Is the `name-p` something that should be in every package?